# Assign a button a date to be visible

Tags: javascript, button

Right now all buttons are visible and disappears after I click it. I would like the buttons to show within a certain time period. Show one button for the week on the button. Don't show all buttons at one time. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script>
    function enableButton(thisButton, nextButton) {
    thisButton.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(nextButton).disabled = false;
    }
</script>

<center> MUST ONLY SHOW 1 BUTTON PER WEEK!!!!NOT ALL</center>
<br />
<center>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="September 1 - September 5"  
     onclick="enableButton(this, 'button2')" /><br>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="September 8 - September 13" 
     disabled onclick="enableButton(this, 'button3')" /><br>
<input type="button" id="button3" value="September 16 - September 20"   
     disabled onclick="enableButton(this, 'button4')" /><br>
<input type="button" id="button4" value="September 23 - September 27"  
     disabled onclick="enableButton(this, 'button5')" /><br>
</center>
```

Comment: If it's september 1, you only want to show the button that says September 1 - September 5?

Comment: I only want the sept 1 - sept 5 button to appear and show during those dates. Then hide itself again.